# How to make buttons on a canvas in J2ME?

Tags: java, button, java-me, canvas

I'm new to J2ME and I was trying to make a page which has some logos(images) at the top, two buttons arranged side-by-side(one and only one of which is always selected) and a table displaying data below the buttons. The data is displayed according to which button is currently selected. I'm extending `canvas` and I was able to make the tables and draw the images but I could'nt find anything on making buttons on the internet. So how should I go about it? If anyone could point me to some sample code, that would be great too!

Comment: Look on this [useful discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295877/button-image-problem). I suggest go with some 3rd party framework. LWUIT is good to use.

Comment: Seems a bit too much for J2ME, not impossible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iirc my favorite way to paint buttons on canvas was drawing and filling rounded rectangles. There are methods in [Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html) package that do that; to get desired effect I just called them with same or off-by-one parameters I don't recall exactly.

- note if you are going to write text over "buttons", consider using `Font.getHeight` and `Font.stringWidth` to determine size of rectangle to draw around

---

> ...logos(images) at the top, two buttons arranged side-by-side(one and only one of which is always selected) and a table displaying data below the buttons

BTW is there a reason why you don't use `Form`? I ask because `StringItem` objects, created with appearance `BUTTON` and having `ItemCommandListener` look and behave like buttons but are easier to code. The rest also looks doable with `Form`, one just may need `CustomItem` to display the table like you describe

Comment: Hmm...I'll try the 'form' way and see if it helps

Comment: the problem is that the two buttons are side-by-side like a tab-bar. How should I add buttons in one row of a form?

Comment: fixed it! there were some width issues. Thanks for making me shift to the form method!

Answer (score 2):

Not that hard, but you need to draw everything yourself.  That means, buttons are either using a plain rectangle with text in the middle (different colours could indicate which is highlighted), or they could be images which you made yourself.

If they are arranged in a square, you need to keep track of which button is selected, and then change the selected index whenever a direction key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The default UI does not have buttons, only commands. You have to make one yourself or use a GUI framework like LWUit.